# Partition by list using expressions

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, partitioning

I want to partition a table in a way I always know where the record is going. For instance, if I had a telephone list and 10 partitions, I'd like to guide to guide each telephone number based on it's last digit.

Worth mentioning I'm on Oracle 11gR2

`PARTITION BY LIST` however, doesn't seem to allow that.

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    tel INT NOT NULL
)
PARTITION BY LIST ( MOD (tel,10) )
      (PARTITION MSISDN0 VALUES (0),
       PARTITION MSISDN1 VALUES (1),
       PARTITION MSISDN2 VALUES (2),
       PARTITION MSISDN3 VALUES (3),
       PARTITION MSISDN4 VALUES (4),
       PARTITION MSISDN5 VALUES (5),
       PARTITION MSISDN6 VALUES (6),
       PARTITION MSISDN7 VALUES (7),
       PARTITION MSISDN8 VALUES (8),
       PARTITION MSISDN9 VALUES (9));

Erro de SQL: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis
00907. 00000 -  "missing right parenthesis"
```

It seems `LIST PARTITIONS` won't accept functions. Still I managed with a virtual column:

```
CREATE TABLE t (
    tel INT NOT NULL
    , tel_p GENERATED ALWAYS AS ( mod (tel,10) )
)
PARTITION BY LIST ( tel_p )
      (PARTITION MSISDN0 VALUES (0),
       PARTITION MSISDN1 VALUES (1),
       PARTITION MSISDN2 VALUES (2),
       PARTITION MSISDN3 VALUES (3),
       PARTITION MSISDN4 VALUES (4),
       PARTITION MSISDN5 VALUES (5),
       PARTITION MSISDN6 VALUES (6),
       PARTITION MSISDN7 VALUES (7),
       PARTITION MSISDN8 VALUES (8),
       PARTITION MSISDN9 VALUES (9));
```

though it feels rather wonky...
Is there a "proper way" to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the way you have done it ***is the right way***. You can read specifically about that functionality in Oracle's documentation:

> ### Virtual Column-Based Partitioning
>
> In previous releases of the Oracle Database, a table could only be
>   partitioned if the partitioning key physically existed in the table.
>   In Oracle Database 11g, **virtual columns remove that restriction and
>   allow the partitioning key to be defined by an expression**, using one
>   or more existing columns of a table. The expression is stored as
>   metadata only.
>
> Oracle Partitioning has been enhanced to allow a partitioning strategy
>   to be defined on virtual columns. For example, a 10 digit account ID
>   can include account branch information as the leading 3 digits. With
>   the extension of virtual column based Partitioning, an ACCOUNTS table
>   containing an ACCOUNT_ID column can be extended with a virtual
>   (derived) column ACCOUNT_BRANCH that is derived from the first three
>   digits of the ACCOUNT_ID column, which becomes the partitioning key
>   for this table.
>
> Virtual column-based Partitioning is supported with all basic
>   partitioning strategies, including interval and interval-* composite
>   partitioning.

Source: [Oracle Documentation - Partitioning](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b32024/partition.htm)